# Limit loop to future events

Tags: wp-query, date

I have a custom post type, `basic_events`, with a custom date field, `date_of_event`. My view shows these posts in ascending order, based on this custom date field.

```
$args = array( 
     'post_type' => array('basic_events'),
     'order'     => 'ASC',
     'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',
     'meta_key'  => 'date_of_event',
     'paged'     => $paged
);
```

Since everything is sorted by that field, and not by post type or an internal WordPress date, I'm having a hard time figuring out how to limit this view to only show FUTURE events.

What is the best way to limit to view to future events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your date is in the correct format for proper ordering (yyyy-mm-dd), add a [`meta_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) to your args:

```
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => array('basic_events'),
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key' => 'date_of_event',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
                'key' => 'date_of_event',
                'value' => date( 'Y-m-d', current_time( 'timestamp' ) ),
                'compare' => '>',
                'type' => 'DATE'
        )
    )
);
```

**EDIT**- Changed `date( 'Y-m-d' )` to `date( 'Y-m-d', current_time( 'timestamp' ) )` to get the date relative to your site's timezone settings. See [`current_time`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_time) in Codex for info.

Comment: This was perfect! One followup question: Currently, it appears to be using UTC to calculate the date, but my timezone is PST. How would I alter this inside the meta_query?

Comment: use `date( 'Y-m-d', current_time( 'timestamp' ) )` to get your site's local date.